# NSString initialization

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

Objective-C noob here.

Why would this:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString alloc];
[myString initWithFormat:@"%f", storedNumber];
```

results in the following exception `-length only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSPlaceholderString length]!`

When this works just fine:

`NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", storedNumber];`

I would think that the latter is merely a contraction of the former (but I'm obviously wrong, at least according to the compiler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `-initWithFormat:` is returning an object that’s different from the one returned by `+alloc`, i.e., an object that’s different from the one pointed by `myString`. That’s the reason why you should always couple `+alloc` with `-init…`.

This situation is common in class clusters such as `NSString`. `+alloc` returns a generic string object, then `-initWithFormat:` decides upon a concrete subclass of `NSString`, deallocates the current object created by `+alloc`, creates a new object from a concrete subclass of `NSString`, and then returns this new object.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

or

```
NSString *myString = [NSString new];
```